# Change JCheckBox/JRadioButton selection color

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jradiobutton, uimanager

Is there a way to change the selection color of a checkbox/radiobutton?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to do it for a JCheckBox

```
UIManager.put("CheckBox.focus",Color.RED);
```

There is a nice tool here: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/ that if you run the Java Web Start program it will allow you to browse the keys and values for each component.

Comment: Works, thank you. Also for jRadioButton: UIManager.put("RadioButton.focus", Color.RED);