# JRadioButton selection color

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, awt, jradiobutton

When any Radio Button in my Java UI program is selected, the selection is shown by a *black* dot. I want to make it Green. I'm using Java Swing. I followed the answer given to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607107/change-jcheckbox-jradiobutton-selection-color) , but it's not working for me. It still shows a black dot when selected.

```
public class OptionFrame extends JFrame {
 
     public OptionFrame(){
            UIManager.put("RadioButton.focus", new ColorUIResource(Color.GREEN));
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
     }
}
```

I'm unable to understand why above code is not working. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Change foreground color, instead of focus color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't set JPanel color and JRadioButton invisibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085840/cant-set-jpanel-color-and-jradiobutton-invisibility).

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: possible opportunity for [JRadioButton: how to replace text by IconImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6774987/230513).

Comment: @trashgod , No, this is different from the question you posted. Background color affects the area around the radio buttons, and IconImage only adds an icon to the side of the radio button. Only other similar question is the one I have posted in my question.

Comment: @sanjeevmk: I've tried to explain below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm unable to understand why above code is not working.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14086162/230513), the appearance is controlled by the Look & Feel dependent UI delegate. The delegate is free to render the dot however it pleases; some ignore the defaults and delegate to a host platform component.  Short of writing your own `ButtonUI`, replacing the `Icon` is the next best thing. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036048/230513) illustrates the effect for the selected state of `JToggleButton`, the parent of `JRadioButton`. `ColorIcon`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), is also handy in this context, and more examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6774987/230513).

Comment: @sanjeev mk JRadioButton has paintIcon,